How to compile a kernel module so that the *.ko file can work on different versions of the kernel?
I want to implement a feature through a kernel module, and I hope to achieve this functionality only by providing the *.ko file, making it effective on machines with different kernel versions through insmod command without needing to recompile the source code every time on a different machine.
How could I achieve this functionality?

This might not be possible because of System.map dependencies.

@StephenNewell How are the mainstream kernel-live-patches or device-drivers solving this problem? Do they need to provide source codes for each version of the kernel and perform on-site compilation?

With binary distributions, modules are built against a specific kernel.  With source-based distributions, you rebuild modules yourself on kernel changes.  The module's source doesn't have to change, but you are supposed to recompile.

It is possible to supply a prebuilt filename.o renamed as filename.o_shipped. You still need to build a shim from source to act as an interface between the kernel API and the prebuilt API. That shim will be kernel specific, so the resulting .ko file will also be kernel specific. NVidia graphics DRM drivers do something like that.
